# Yoast increase displayed pages

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I currently pull through breadcrumbs from Yoast `<?php yoast_breadcrumb('<p>','</p>'); ?>` but it only pulls in the current page, and its parent.

Is there any way it can pull through the whole route up to the homepage?

I've checked the settings and theres nothing! 
All up to date with plugins and WP if that helps.